# Using ArcMap Join and symbology

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, spatial-join, excel

I'm still new into the GIS World, and here's what I'm trying to achieve. I have Yemen administrative shapefile with list of governments, and districts, I also have an Excel file with a list of migrants information. One of the fields in that Excel file is the government where that migrant was encountered.

How do I show how many migrants were encountered in each government in the map?

I could join the Excel data with the shapefile, but I didn't know how to count how many migrants with the same government and project it on the map using the symbology.

Comment: How is excel file structured? Do you have _one_ line _for each_ Migrant_ (person) in excel?

Comment: Yes of course every migrant in a record the following are the columns in the excel file and that how it's structured : MigrantID MigrantName MaritalStatues Religion Education JobBeforeMigration Age Gender DateEncount PlaceOfArriv Government PortOfDeparture DateOfDeparture AreaOfArrival DateOfArrival Nationality Ethnicity  Incidents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000064000000) between the Excel sheet and the shapefile of your administrative polygons (you use the column with government/municipality name in Excel and in shapefile). You will get the Excel sheet columns appended to the shapefile.
2. Now you can [export your shapefile](http://support.esri.com/zh-cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/20931) from the table of contents to a new feature class in geodatabase or just shapefile (this will preserve the fields you have joined from Excel).
3. When you will add the exported shapefile to the ArcMap map document, you can use your fields data to symbolize your features based on the numeric values (Layer Properties > Symbology tab).

If you want to aggregate information about number of people within multiple administrative areas that belong to a certain larger administrative division (e.g., many counties within a state), you can run [Dissolve GP tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Dissolve/00170000005n000000/) to group multiple polygons that share a certain attribute value (i.e., name of the state) and then specify the statistics field for which the values will be summed. This implies output polygons of states will contain the sum of population of all counties that belong to this state.

If you need to use some other statistics method (finding average etc.), you use the Statistics fields parameter in the Dissolve GP tool dialog box (`statistics_fields`).

[image]

Comment: Very helpful , i will try this out and comeback if i still have any further questions related to the same issue

Comment: It worked magically and the summery counted all the aggregated attributes, but i was wondering is counting the only statistical operation i can make on my tables or there are others , and if yes how i can choose which statistical operation to do such as MAX,MUN,Average .

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please don't forget to upvote answers you find useful and avoid asking in comments - it is better to start a new question :)

Comment: I need 15 points to do that , i'm still new i will return back and vote once i get those pints .

Answer (score 2):

You have to summarize the Excel table *before* you join it. To summarize the Excel table you can use Excel's pivot functions or you can use ArcGIS:

1. Add Excel table to ArcGIS.
2. Summarize Excel table - [see Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000055000000). Right-click on field Government. It does not matter what statistics you compute. A field called *count* will automatically calculated.
3. Join summarized table to your shapefile
4. Symbolize your features based on the numeric values in field *count*.

Comment: I Think that will do, I'll try it and comeback with the results